# Android stop playing ringtone when connected to channel (AGORA SDK)

Tags: java, android, agora.io

I have implemented ringtone behaviour, I want it to continuously ring until someone join the channel!
Currently, when I play the custom ringtone, as soon as I join the channel the ringtone gets stopped. I am trying to call 1 to 1 calling no group calling.

**What I did**

```
 PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                //Incoming call: Pause music
                PhoneCallTunes.activateRingtone(mActivity);
            } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                //Not in call: Play music
            } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                //A call is dialing, active or on hold
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };

    private void phoneStateListener(){
        TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) mActivity.getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if(mgr != null) {
            mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }

    }
```

I have implemented the above code and things are working fine but there is a lag in the ringtone as the pattern is like

**Ringtone -- > channel join detected and AGORA forcefully stop the ring tone -- > then i override the CALL_STATE_RINGING to re-enable the ringtone**

Comment: Did you get this issue fixed? What is PhoneCallTunes in your code?